# Python: How to generates diferents dataframes from a list already pre-loaded

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dear Community I am trying to generates multiple dataframes from a list already pre-loaded and store them with diferent dataframes names.First I call the names of specific excel files I wanted to cal from a folder as:

```
list = info.files.dropma()
```

These will store the list of the files that I only want to read from a particular folder.

Then I store the multiples excel files into a list ("of dataframes") as:

```
d = []
for f in list:
    li = pd.read_excel(f)
    d.append(li)
```

Above, d generates a list with multiple Dataframes.

Then I create a list with numbers, in order to identify the indexs from the list as:

```
list_2 = [i for i in range(0,len(lista)]
```

Later I call a list with the names I anted to call my new dataframes

```
names = info.names
```

After that, I use the information from "list_2" and "names", in order to: i) loop over the index od the lis 'd' (which cointains the info from different excel files), and ii) label my new dataframes, as:

```
for i in list_2
    for i_2 in names 
        vars()[i_2] = pd.DataFrame(d[i])
```

Although there is no error, and the loop works, and generates the new dataframes, the code does not store the info in an accurate way. The situation here is that, the code repeats the last info from the list "d" and store then along the multiple dataframes.

Is there any way to fix this?

I will apreciate any comment or any help, please.

Comment: The first thing to fix is never to use the names of built-in functions as names of your own objects. You may want to use a code editor with Python syntax highlighting to help spot such conflicts. E.g. `list` is a built-in function, so you should not name some list like that. Similarly, in your last line of code, do you really intend to assign something to the dictionary returned by the built-in `vars` function? That wouldn't work according to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars

Comment: Many Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do the following:

```
files_list = info.files.dropma() 
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in files_list]
names = info.names
for name, df in zip(names, dfs):
    vars()[name] = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

This is using 2 basic Python-features:

- [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): To quote from the docs:

  > List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of some operations applied to each member of another sequence or iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a certain condition.
- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip): Among other things, the builtin function `zip` is the goto tool for synchroized looping over several iterables (here 2 lists).

As mentioned by Arne in their comment:

- Don't use `list` as variable name - you're overriding the name of a builtin type.
- `vars()` works as long as `locals()` is identical with `globals()` (`print(id(vars()) == id(globals()))` should yield `True`). It breaks the moment this isn't the case, because `locals()` then is read-only - for example inside a function definition.

Comment: Many thanks for the example, it works. Thank ypu, again.